cf login Unable to authenticate failure
When perform "cf login" , the response is:
API endpoint:   https://api.sys.xxx.com
API version:    3.138.0
Not logged in. Use 'cf login' or 'cf login --sso' to log in.
Unable to authenticate.
FAILED

I used the cli "cf login -a api.sys.xxx.com -u admin -p xxx --skip-ssl-validation -o system -s system -v";
it is the responses:
REQUEST: [2024-04-02T17:37:41+08:00]
GET /login HTTP/1.1
Host: login.sys.xxx.com
Accept: application/json
Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
Connection: close
User-Agent: cf/8.7.9+0fd654c.2024-04-01 (go1.22.1; amd64 linux)

RESPONSE: [2024-04-02T17:37:46+08:00]
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 0
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'
Date: Tue, 02 Apr 2024 09:37:46 GMT
Location: https://login.sys.xxx.com:8443/login
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Vcap-Request-Id: 460ad6b2-8c4f-4c0d-521a-c79276982df4

API endpoint:   https://api.sys.xxx.com
API version:    3.138.0
Not logged in. Use 'cf login' or 'cf login --sso' to log in.
Unable to authenticate.
FAILED

